# How to use Laravel Eloquent ::with() on something you have gained already doing a ::with()?

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js

Hello I am experimenting with vue.js front end and laravel backend and well I can use `Organisation::with('areas')->get();` to get a list of all the organisations and the areas attached to the organisations, but what I am looking to do is also store the sites related to the areas. So more less how do with() inside of a with(). All this information get response->json(); to the vue frontend.

Thank you, Jordan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See "nested eager loading" at https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships. You can use "dot syntax" to fetch nested relationships like this:

```
Organisation::with(['areas', 'areas.sites'])->get();
```